# Error in Armadillo with intel C++ compiler

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, armadillo, icc

I have been using Armadillo 4.2 version (from linux mint package manager) for quite a some time. That version had no problem when compiled with icc, and codes compiled with icc ran very fast (about 10%-15% fast compared to g++).

Recently I have upgraded Armadillo to recent 6.1 version (from the official website). But in this case, all the codes compiled correctly with icc, but gave runtime error.

```
error: eig_sym(): failed to converge

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
what():  eig_sym(): failed to converge
Aborted
```

Codes compiled correctly with g++ ran perfectly.
I have also tried previous 5.6 version, but the same problem.
Any solutions?? I had to revert back to old 4.2 version to get that extra speed from icc...

Answer (score 1):

The Intel C++ compiler is known to contain of bugs when dealing with heavily templated libraries like Armadillo (see for example [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-c-compiler/topic/542333) and [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-c-compiler/topic/506815)).

You can increase the performance of gcc compiled code by enabling auto-vectorization (using `-O3`) and using the native machine instruction set (using `-march=native`). For example:

```
g++ code.cpp -o code -O3 -march=native -larmadillo
```

Also make sure that the matrix you're passing to [eig_sym()](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#eig_sym) is actually symmetric.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is unfortunate to have bugs in Intel C++ compiler (even though it is the latest version). I have also encountered one bug in icc regarding vector construction with initializer lists.    Btw, I am using `-O3` and `-march=native` with g++, and the matrix is symmetric.

Comment: Based on my experience I don't trust the Intel compiler. The minor speedups it provides just aren't worth the hassle with all the bugs it has. I suspect the development team for the Intel compiler is far smaller than for gcc or clang.